# Magento Filter Custom EAV by Attribute Error

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

I am unable to filter a custom eav collection, that otherwise performs normally:

```
$mymodel = Mage::getModel('mymodel/things');
$collection = $mymodel->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Various attempts are made to filter the collection, e.g.:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('my_attribute','1');

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute', array('like' => '1'));
```

anything I try throws this error:

```
Invalid method Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::isScopeGlobal(Array
(
)
)

#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Collection\Abstract.php(186): Varien_Object->__call('isScopeGlobal', Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Collection\Abstract.php(186): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute->isScopeGlobal()
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and direction.

UPDATE:

Hacking the following and ->addAttributeToFilter works as it should.  Still need a proper solution to the custom model.  Thank you.

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract:  **Hacked**
Line186  if ($store_id != $this->getDefaultStoreId() ){ //&& !$attribute->isScopeGlobal()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The principle issue was extending the wrong class in my custom model resource collection class:

```
was:  ... extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract
now:  ... extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
```